# jquery 'show' + 'animate' only working on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, show

I'm having a bit of trouble with show and animate used together. I want the box to show and fade in *each time* my_ids are clicked and to fade out whenever any other part of the page is clicked.
But as it stands the animate to opacity: '1' only works on the first click.

This is my third day learning jQuery (/javascript) and this is most of what I've learnt, so extra dumbed down answers would be appreciated :)

Relevant HTML :

```
     <html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
          <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet-june3.css">

    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div class="folio-experience-4" id="EWF20">
                  <div class="experience-title-highlight" id="EWF20-1">
                          <a href="https://emergingwritersfestival.org.au/emerging-writers-festival/">Emerging Writers' Festival</a><br>
                    <div class="experience-title-highlight" display="inline" style="text-align:right; padding-right:20px;" id="EWF20-3">-- Digital Producer
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="experience-description-highlight" id="EWF20-2">
                        ONLINE CURATOR FOR EWF20, ONE OF AUSTRALIA'S MOST ESTABLISHED AND WELL-RESPECTED
                         LITERARY FESTIVALS
                  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-righthand-1-5">
      <div id="EWF20_extra">
        hello ~~~
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#EWF20_extra{
  top:300px;
  display:none;
  border: 1px dashed;
  border-radius:50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

jQuery /javascript:

```
 <script>
    
         $(document).ready(function(){
        
       var my_ids = ["EWF20", "EWF20-1", "EWF20-2", "EWF20-3"]
       
        $("html").on('click', my_ids, function(e) {
          
          if (my_ids.includes(e.target.id)) {
            console.log("Doing my thang!")
          }
          /* >> is the id of the thing targeted (clicked on) included in my_ids */
          if (e.target.id == "EWF20" || e.target.id == "EWF20-1" || e.target.id == "EWF20-2" || e.target.id == "EWF20-3"){
            $("#EWF20_extra").show().animate({opacity: '1'}, 2000);
          } else {
            $("#EWF20_extra").fadeOut(1000);
          }
        });
      }); 
    
  </script>
```

Thank you so much in advance for your help! :))

Comment: Is there any reason why you are doing it this way? Rather than using ``.fadeIn()``?

The problem you are having is because ``opacity:1`` is being left on the object. It's going to get more complicated to create a work around when there's already a function you can use.

Comment: No reason other than that this is some of the first javascript / jQuery I am learning and I watched a tutorial that demonstrated animate opacity rather than fadeIn. I changed to fadeIn and now it's working great! Thx to all the answers

Comment: Ah k, great! I thought there may have been a requirement to do it that way which is why I wanted to check before working on a solution for you. Seeing you can use fadeIn, then certainly do it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `opacity` is the problem, as `fadeOut` uses `display`.

```
if (e.target.id == "EWF20" || e.target.id == "EWF20-1" || e.target.id == "EWF20-2" || e.target.id == "EWF20-3") {
      $("#EWF20_extra").fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
      $("#EWF20_extra").fadeOut(1000);
    }
```

**Note** I removed `opacity`

```
#EWF20_extra{
  top:300px;
  border: 1px dashed;
  border-radius:50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

Also, you have (2) other problems. In your element, `EWF20-1`, there's an `href`, meaning that if you click that, it'll redirect the user to the endpoint, so that element (the `a` tag) won't work for show/hide. Additionally, I would recommend either targeting the class, `experience-description-highlight` instead of using IDs (if that class won't be used for any conflicting additional JS events).

The reason I suggest using classes instead of IDs is b/c, in the event you add another "element", you won't have to hard-code your JS script (which you're doing already w/ your IDs, since you're not targeting a container, but rather an array of IDs. Hence it's better to use class names.

Last but not least, it's best to format your HTML/JS/CSS, etc before submitting it to stackoverflow. Makes it easier to read, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Since you write that you are learning jQuery, I would advise you to use more classes and HTML5 markup instead of IDs. Further the code can get some performance optimizations.

Further you can simply use `fadeToggle` instead of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.
Maybe my example can help you.

```js
var $content = $('#content');

$('.folio-experience').on('click', toggleFade);

function toggleFade(e) {
  $content.find($(e.currentTarget).data('target')).fadeToggle(1000);
}
```

```css
.experience-job {
  padding-right: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

.folio-experience-content {
  display: none;
  top: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dashed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="folio-experience" data-target="#EWF20">
  <div class="experience-title">
    <a href="https://emergingwritersfestival.org.au/emerging-writers-festival/">
      Emerging Writers' Festival
    </a>
    <div class="experience-job">
      -- Digital Producer
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="experience-description">
    ONLINE CURATOR FOR EWF20, ONE OF AUSTRALIA'S MOST ESTABLISHED AND WELL-RESPECTED
    LITERARY FESTIVALS
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="content-righthand">
  <div id="EWF20" class="folio-experience-content">
    hello ~~~
  </div>
</div>
```